# Reading lines in text files using python

Tags: python, file, wxpython

I am currently programming a game that requires reading and writing lines in a text file. I was wondering if there is a way to read a specific line in the text file (i.e. the first line in the text file). Also, is there a way to write a line in a specific location (i.e. change the first line in the file, write a couple of other lines and then change the first line again)? I know that we can read lines sequentially by calling:

```
f.readline()
```

Edit: Based on responses, apparently there is no way to read specific lines if they are different lengths. I am only working on a small part of a large group project and to change the way I'm storing data would mean a lot of work.

But is there a method to change specifically the first line of the file? I know calling:

```
f.write('text')
```

Writes something into the file, but it writes the line at the end of the file instead of the beginning. Is there a way for me to specifically rewrite the text at the beginning?

Comment: Short answer: No, unless you know the lengths of all the lines. This is independent of the programming language used - how else would you know which line you're on unless you're counting newlines?

Comment: How might I go about changing the first line of the file. As far as I know, calling file.write('line') writes the line at the end of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your lines are guaranteed to be the same length, then you can use `f.seek(N)` to position the file pointer at the N'th byte (where N is LINESIZE*line_number) and then `f.read(LINESIZE)`.  Otherwise, I'm not aware of any way to do it in an ordinary ASCII file (which I think is what you're asking about).

Of course, you could store some sort of record information in the header of the file and read that first to let you know where to seek to in your file -- but at that point you're better off using some external library that has already done all that work for you.

Unless your text file is really big, you can always store each line in a list:

```
with open('textfile','r') as f:
    lines=[L[:-1] for L in f.readlines()]
```

(note I've stripped off the newline so you don't have to remember to keep it around)

Then you can manipulate the list by adding entries, removing entries, changing entries, etc.
At the end of the day, you can write the list back to your text file:

```
with open('textfile','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Here's a little test which works for me on OS-X to replace only the first line.

*test.dat*

```
this line has n characters
this line also has n characters
```

*test.py*

```
#First, I get the length of the first line -- if you already know it, skip this block
f=open('test.dat','r')
l=f.readline()
linelen=len(l)-1
f.close()

#apparently mode='a+' doesn't work on all systems :( so I use 'r+' instead
f=open('test.dat','r+')
f.seek(0)
f.write('a'*linelen+'\n') #'a'*linelen = 'aaaaaaaaa...' 
f.close()
```

Comment: Is there a way to read the file and append to it at the same time? I'm currently appending something into the file, but it's not letting me read the file at the same time.

Comment: I think that `open('filename','a+')` should allow you to read/write from the file.  Note that immediately after opening, the file pointer will be at the end of the file, so in order to actually read anything from it, you'll need to `f.seek(0)` to get back to the beginning.  (you could store the end point with `f.tell()`) so you can go back to the end anytime you want though...

Comment: '\n'.join(lines) <-- '\n' is odd here. readlines() will return list of lines with their new lines chars, i.e. with '\n'.

Comment: @stalk -- Thanks.  I rarely use `readlines` so I forgot it left the trailing newline.  I've updated so that the newlines are stripped off when reading.

Comment: how about editing the first line of the file? Is there a way for me to edit specifically the first line of the file?

Comment: @user1246462 Again, you can seek to the beginning and replace that line with something else -- but whatever you replace it with should be the same length as the original line -- You can pad it with newlines, or spaces -- depending on how the other program expects it to be formatted.

Comment: What would be the exact code I would write if I were to change the first line? I'm sorry for being tedious but this is the first time I'm attempting to manipulate a data file using python.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last, and hopefully, short question. The code you posted doesn't delete the first line and replace it with a new line? At least when I tested it, it simply adds whatever you type in "write" to the beginning of the line but doesn't replace it completely.

Comment: @user1246462 -- The code I posted works for me.  Did you replace `f.write('a'*linelen+'\n')` with something else?  If so, you have to make sure that the string has `linelen` characters in it.  If your string is shorter, you'll need to pad it with spaces (which hopefully won't mess up the program that reads the datafile).

Answer (score 0):

These days, jumping within files in an optimized fashion is a task for high performance applications that manage huge files.

Are you sure that your software project **requires** reading/writing random places in a file during runtime? I think you should consider changing the whole approach:

If the data is small, you can keep / modify / generate the data at runtime in memory within appropriate container formats (list or dict, for instance) and then write it entirely at once (on change, or only when your program exits). You could consider looking at simple databases. Also, there are nice data exchange formats like JSON, which would be the ideal format in case your data is stored in a dictionary at runtime.

An example, to make the concept more clear. Consider you already have data written to `gamedata.dat`:

```
[{"playtime": 25, "score": 13, "name": "rudolf"}, {"playtime": 300, "score": 1, "name": "peter"}]
```

This is utf-8-encoded and JSON-formatted data. Read the file during runtime of your Python game:

```
with open("gamedata.dat") as f:
    s = f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Convert the data to Python types:

```
gamedata = json.loads(s)
```

Modify the data (add a new user):

```
user = {"name": "john", "score": 1337, "playtime": 1}
gamedata.append(user)
```

John really is a 1337 gamer. However, at this point, you also could have deleted a user, changed the score of Rudolf or changed the name of Peter, ... In any case, after the modification, you can simply write the new data back to disk:

```
with open("gamedata.dat", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(gamedata).encode("utf-8"))
```

The point is that you manage (create/modify/remove) data during runtime **within appropriate container types**. When writing data to disk, you write the entire data set in order to save the current state of the game.

Comment: Yes, the file will be read later on in another program so there is no other way for me to not write the file.

Comment: This is why you should "write it entirely at once (on change, or only when your program exits)" at some point in time, after you have performed the data manipulation in, for example, a dictionary :)